# I have some problem in logging in

Tags: battery, logging

When I tried to log onto my user ID, it does not accept any password.  Previously also, I used to confront the same problem. But then, I would go for opting 'switch user option' when a circular shaped icon would appear, by clicking which I could choose between Ubuntu and Ubuntu2D. Then logging in would be possible. But unfortunately that's not happening any more.  As a result, I am unable to even switch off the laptop.  I have simply to let the charge of the battery drain out completely.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds as though your problem might not be that you've forgotten your password, but that Unity is not starting correctly due to some configuration error. Perhaps your problem started after installing Nvidia drivers or Radeon drivers?

Depending on what is causing your problem there are a number of solutions you could try:

1.) Uninstall your nvidia or radeon drivers:

Hold down CTRL and ALT and F2 together. This should take you to a login prompt where you can type your username, and your password. Once in, type this to remove your drivers:

sudo apt-get purge nvidia* fglrx*
( you may need to do more than that to get rid of the drivers if you installed the binary versions from the AMD and Nvidia websites)

2.) If you've just installed Ubuntu and have never been able to log in with this version, it may be because your hardware is too old to support 3D graphics, and in this case I'd recommend you install Lubuntu instead:
http://lubuntu.net/

3.) If you can't log in at all it may be because you have set your password incorrectly or you've forgotten your password.
Here are some instructions on how to reset your password in Linux:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-reset-forgotten-root-password/

But when you get to the bit where you enter "passwd" put your user name in front of the command. So on my computer it looks like: passwd damonsaccount
Where as for your user account it may look like: passwd Manasbs788

You can also create a new user account while you're there by doing:
useradd Manasbs788

then: passwd Manasbs788
(and entering a password, making sure to write it down somewhere for later!)